# Column cut into two lines in Internet explorer

Tags: html, css, xml, internet-explorer, xslt

I am using tablr in IE

```
<table style="width=74%;table-layout:auto" border="0">
<xsl:for-each select="webpage/param">    
<tr>
 <xsl:if test="@type !='i'">  
    <td class="rowYellow">
    <xsl:if test="@indent !=''">  

        <!-- Generate the appropriate number of indentation -->
        <xsl:variable name="count" select="@indent"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="(//*)[position()&lt;=$count]">
            <xsl:text>&#xA0;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
```

THis code works good in Mozilla but in IE my column goes into two lines instead of doing auto layout.

Comment: put `white-space:nowrap;` on it?

Comment: Sorry I didnt get ur valuable comment, Can you explain little more

Comment: -1 poor question, bad spelling and wrong tags!

Comment: Please change `width=74%;` to `width: 74%;` Your working in a style tag so you have to use css syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

valuable comment expanded:

your column, i assume is one or more of the table columns. you dont want the text in it to be on 2 lines?

add css rule:

```
td {
  white-space:nowrap;
}
```

Comment: Yes its tabl column issue only, Can I give liek this 
<table style="width=74%;table-layout:auto" border="0">
td {
  white-space:nowrap;
}

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is set some styling for your table cell. You already have done so, but have some basic errors in your code.

First, please try to understand some basic HTML and CSS. You will find good resources with google, like this one: http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/011/firstcss.en.html

Comment: THanks. I am very new to this programming. Link is very basic and good for starter thanks